# Photoshop: how to resize multiple artboards?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, automation, artboard

Is there a way / script / workaround to re-scale multiple artboards including their contents (not just the canvas size)?

Ie.  I have a PSB with 10-15 artboards. Each artboard is 1242 x 2208 and need to scale each one up to 1440 x 2560.

When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> I get the Image size panel, but this shows me the whole master document size (size of all the artboards and the spaces between them combined).

I've seen many variations of this questions across many boards but haven't found a decent answer.

Answer (score 1):

From iPhone 6/6S/7 PLUS size to Android's larger resolution screen.

You're probably going to have to increase the size of the entire image by the amount of difference. Luckily they're both 16:9 aspect ratios.

Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and scale up by a percentage of **1.15942028985507**.

This should leave you with all artboards at the right size.

Comment: First of all thanks! that was my first approach. Though the problem is that its a very very heavy document and it takes about 2-3 hours to scale everything. I was wondering if there is a slickier way..

Comment: You could copy the original document, and then begin cropping to each artboard and saving each out as unique files. About the only way you're going to get performance back. Photoshop and big files aren't friends

Answer (score 0):

For Photoshop you can try my script: "Transform with style".

Video preview:

[image: GIF]

Download here: http://bereza.cz/ps/

Features:

- Intuitive control. Just transform layers as usually
- Works with multiple layers simultaneously
- Supports layer effects and shape styles
- Keeps proportions by default
- Possibility to change the settings in the script (true/false values inside the file)

Answer (score 0):

i know... quite old ;)

1. select multiple artboards in the layers palette
2. select the "artboard tool" (shortcut "V", behind the "move tool")
3. use the context menu (at the top) and change the width/height values